# Question on Beamer Counter

Tags: beamer, numbering, counters

I'm trying to create a new numbered `definition` environment based on `exampleblock`, but it doesn't work as is expected.

My code:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass[serif, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{definition}
\renewenvironment{definition}[1][]
    {\stepcounter{definition}\begin{exampleblock}{Definition\,\arabic{definition}}}
    {\end{exampleblock}}

\begin{frame}
    \onslide<1->
    \begin{definition}
        qwq1 % expected to be "Definition 1"
    \end{definition}
    \onslide<2->
    \begin{definition}
        qwq2 % expected to be "Definition 2"
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, the slide looks like

[image]

Could someone show me how to use counter with `\onslide` properly?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please complete your code to compilable small document (missed is document preamble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, just use beamers build in `definition` environment and activate theorem numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}<1->
        qwq1 % expected to be "Definition 1"
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}<2->
        qwq2 % expected to be "Definition 2"
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In case the blue colour of this `definition` environment is bothering you, it can be changed like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=example text.fg!75!black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
        \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
        \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{definition}<1->
        qwq1 % expected to be "Definition 1"
    \end{definition}
    \begin{definition}<2->
        qwq2 % expected to be "Definition 2"
    \end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm still curious about the reason why my code doesn't work as is expected. Could you please tell me the reason?

Comment: @C.R.Wang The reason that your code did not work is that the code is executed on each slide of the frame. For your code this means that on the second slide the counter starts not at zero but at 2. As a workaround you could manually reset the counter with `\begin{frame}
 \setcounter{definition}{0}`

Comment: Oh...It seems that the number goes wrong again when I replace `\onslide` with `\only`.

Comment: @C.R.Wang That's the difference between "not there" and "not visible"